# Extracting dates from scan with Tesseract (OCR) proving difficult. Assistance required

Tags: image, ocr, tesseract, text-extraction

I am finding it difficult to extract the dates from the scan below.
Would seem straight forward but the results are not very good.
I've tried to use TextCleaner/Convert to pre-process the image to no avail.
Can anyone help?

[image: Scan that I need to extract dates from.]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you shoudl consider picking better OCR. Tesseract is free and good enough for many purposes, but it is no comparison with leading commertial OCR engines. Here's what ABBYY can do with this image without any prior scaling up or preprocessing (it does all the preprocessing needed automatically). It not only picked up all the text, but also the digits:

[image]

You can play around yourself using [demo tool here](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Demo) (no registration required). For that particular result I selected "English"/"Text Extraction"/"Auto" parameters.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY